# Marshal and unmarshal multiple possible objects on a single spring boot endpoint using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a single endpoint that needs to be able to marshal and unmarshal whatever object that it may receive, of a set number of possible objects.

I have tried overloading the endpoint, but I can't seem to do that based on the request body alone.

I have looked into JAXBElement, but it didn't want to work as the type of the argument.

I tried creating an object where all of its variables were XMLRootElements but that doesn't seem to be possible.

I know I can simply return a generic object, my problem is the type of the argument that I receive.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Please share the code and relevant xml content